# How to make 3 horizontal, responsive background images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to create 3 background images that are horizontally aligned, and span `100% width` of the browser but have a maximum height of `800px;` I also want them to scale down responsive. I am using the [glorious bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) As of now you can't see images b/c it's not reading height.

***HTML***

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important">
            <a href="mysite">
                <div class="casestudy-panel" style="background: url(myimage.jpg );"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important">
            <a href="mysite">
                <div class="casestudy-panel" style="background: url(myimage.jpg );"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important">
            <a href="mysite">
                <div class="casestudy-panel" style="background: url(myimage.jpg );"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
    .casestudy-panel{
        max-width:100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .casestudy-panel img {
        max-width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
       -moz-background-size: cover!important;
        background-size: cover!important;
       -o-background-size: cover!important; 

}
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP source. Also, consider using the Stack Snippets feature (icon looks like a page with angle brackets).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan rendered html is up. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using the image as a background the browser it's not going to know the height. You could set the height yourself but that won't maintain the aspect ratio. You may have to use the padding ratio trick for this. See here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/
Otherwise, maybe you can turn the div with the class `casestudy-panel` into an img tag and set the url into the src attribute.

Comment: I've tried the <img> but I can't figure out how to implement the background-size:cover technique to it. It shows margins and doesn't flush up the images with eachother.

Comment: that concept worked. I gave the casestudy-panel div a bottom-padding of 85% and a width of 100%. thanks m8